# Is is possible to bind an event,to session variable change in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I have a requirement in a (badly designed)shopping cart site on which I have to temporarily disable sale. 
By badly design I mean that many developers have worked on this and many points are repeated creating multiple entry and exit points.
The problem is that the session variable basket can be changed from many places , I don't want to change code at so many places due to laziness or what happens if i left some places?

The silver bullet that i have found is that to never let session "basket" get initialized or set it null so that what ever the entry be the process will never complete at max it will throw error which is ok.

I cannot disable the whole session because the site will lose the other functionality.

My question is it possible to fire a code just session["basket"] = null; whenever anything is changed in session object?

Comment: But session["basket"] is also part of the session.  So when you try to set the basket to some non-null value, your trigger would just set it back to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think you can bind an event in the way you desire whenever the session state changes, unless you write your own session provider.

If I understand your desired debugging approach here, perhaps you can take advantage of a global.asax event temporarily, while you debug the system.

For example you may be able to put your session["basket"] = null; line into the Application_PreSendRequestContent event in the global.asax.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/

I've not done this personally, but it could be worth a try.

Comment: yes, in BeginRequest and EndRequest I am setting the basket to null and is ok though with error thrown, Can you tell me why it is not firing for handlers?  BeginRequest and EndRequest are not being called when jquery is using handlers to add to basket.